# How to create a generic client to query an API and return different types based on API call?

Tags: api, repository, generics

I am building a repository that will request data from an API.
Originally, I had multiple methods in my repository such as `GetOrders()`, `GetOrderItems()` etc.

The majority of these functions had almost the same method body except they:

- Had a different end point URL
- Deserialized the JSON into different objects
- Have a different JSON path variable (eg. SuccessResponse.Body.Orders.Order)

Because the code is almost the same, I want to put this into a class, perhaps something called `{Company}ApiClient` (is this the right name??) that will be responsibly for running the API call and returning the object.

How would I create this class so that I can have the same code but the class can return a different type depending on what it is bringing back from the API? I am assuming I need to use generics but from what I can see, the type is specified at the class level.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an abstract class that defines default behavior for common requests and uses generic type. In java:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> {
    ...
    //When constructed pass additional details if needed
    public AbstractRepository(Class<T> type, String baseURL, Client client) {
        this.type = type;
        this.baseURL = baseURL;
        this.client = client;
    }

    public T findById(final String id) {
        //This is where you actually make the call and if you need to 
        //provide the object type information to whatever means you are 
        //using to deserialize the return
        return client.get(id, ...);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        return client.get(...);
    }

    public T update(final T obj) {
        return client.update(obj, ...);
    }

    public List<T> findAllByTerms(SearchTerms searchTerms) {
        return client.get(formatSearchTerms(searchTerms),...);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then extend this class with your types

```
public class OrderRepository extends AbstractRepository<Order> {

    //Call super constructor, pass values if needed
    public OrderRepository(Client client) {
        super(Order.class, Order.BASE_URL, client);
    }

    //If you need 'special' searches for Order, add them in
    public Integer getTotalOrderCount() {
        return super.findAll().size();
    }

    public List<Order> findAllByOrderType() {
        SearchTerms searchTerms = new SearchTerms();
        searchTerms.add("type", OrderTypes.OVERSEAS);
        return super.finalAllByTerms(searchTerms);
    }
}
```

Then if you want one client class where all calls are initiated you could do that a few ways, my naive way would be to contain all your repositories and methods would proxy to them:

```
public class ApiClient {
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private OrderItemRepository orderItemRepository;

    public ApiClient() {
        //Just an holder
        Client client = new Client("user", "password");
        this.orderRepository = new OrderRepository(client);
        this.orderItemRepository = new OrderItemRepository(client);
    }

    public Order findOrderById(Itneger id) {
        return orderRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Order> findAllOrders() {
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }

    public OrderItem findOrderItemById(Integer id) {
        return orderItemRepository.findById(id);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This looks great. If the abstract class is doing the actual work of calling the API.. What is the purpose of client.get

Comment: And if I have an Order endpoint as well as an OrderItem endpoint, i will have separate instances of the abstract repository for these types. If I want to marry the OrderItem results back into the Order object, should this be done in the Order repository class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use generics (in c#)

```
public class Api<T> where T : new
{
     public T GetById(string id);
}
```

If your object matches the default deserialisation, Say from Json.Net, then it will create and populate them correctly through reflection.

However. I do not recommend this approach as it has a couple of problems.

1: As already mentioned you need to be able to create and populate the object in a generic way. If you have some weird naming or a construction parameter you have problems.

2: All the clients have the same generic Methods. GetById, GetAll etc. If you want something specific, GetByDateOfBirth again you cant do it.

I think it likely the the default httpClient already has the level of genericism you need. Your api clients as you say need only specify the url, path, method name etc